# Need assistance with fixing a JavaFX issue. (I'm fairly new to Java)

Tags: java

I have no idea what went wrong, all I know is that I'm trying to learn JavaFX and my program just suddenly stopped working. I was using NetBeans at the time if it helps. Sorry if it's a stupid question with an easy fix, but I have absolutely no idea what went wrong, and literally only have 2 day's worth of experience using Java.

Input:

```
package javafx.testing;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class JavaFXTesting extends Application {

    //main
    blic static void main(String[] args) {

        launch(args);

    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        primaryStage.show(); //shows the window
        primaryStage.setScene(helloworldscene);
        primaryStage.setTitle("JavaFX Testing"); //sets the window title

        Scene helloworldscene = new Scene(root, 500, 300); //creates a new scene

        Button helloworldbutton = new Button("Hello World"); //creates the button and gives it a display name
        helloworldbutton.setOnAction(e -> System.out.println("Hello World")); //prints "Hello World"

        StackPane root = new StackPane(); //no idea what the hell this one does
        root.getChildren().add(helloworldbutton);


    }

}
```

Output:

```
ant -f "C:\\Users\\andym\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\JavaFX Testing" jfxsa-run
init:
Deleting: C:\Users\andym\Documents\NetBeansProjects\JavaFX Testing\build\built-jar.properties
deps-jar:
Updating property file: C:\Users\andym\Documents\NetBeansProjects\JavaFX Testing\build\built-jar.properties
Compiling 1 source file to C:\Users\andym\Documents\NetBeansProjects\JavaFX Testing\build\classes
C:\Users\andym\Documents\NetBeansProjects\JavaFX Testing\src\javafx\testing\JavaFXTesting.java:67: error: cannot find symbol
        primaryStage.setScene(helloworldscene);
  symbol:   variable helloworldscene
  location: class JavaFXTesting
C:\Users\andym\Documents\NetBeansProjects\JavaFX Testing\src\javafx\testing\JavaFXTesting.java:70: error: cannot find symbol
        Scene helloworldscene = new Scene(root, 500, 300); //creates a new scene
  symbol:   variable root
  location: class JavaFXTesting
2 errors
C:\Users\andym\Documents\NetBeansProjects\JavaFX Testing\nbproject\build-impl.xml:931: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Users\andym\Documents\NetBeansProjects\JavaFX Testing\nbproject\build-impl.xml:271: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Comment: Everyone already knows you need assistance, you don't have to mention it in the title. Edit your title to reflect the actual issue you're asking about. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Did you update your java installation in OS or java version in Netbeans by a chance? Looks like you have lost javafx libraries somehow.

Comment: Please tell us what your program is supposed to do and what the successful output used to be.

Answer (score 1):

the issue is that you used `root` before you declared and initialize it

```
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        ...
        Scene helloworldscene = new Scene(root, 500, 300); //error : root not defined
        ...
        StackPane root = new StackPane(); 
        root.getChildren().add(helloworldbutton);
    }
```

so what should you do ? first you need declare the root , and then create your scene , and then show the stage

like this :

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

    //1 - create the root
    StackPane root = new StackPane();
    //2 - add nodes to the root
    Button helloworldbutton = new Button("Hello World");
    root.getChildren().add(helloworldbutton);
    helloworldbutton.setOnAction(e -> System.out.println("Hello World"));
    //4 - create the scene with the root
    Scene helloworldscene = new Scene(root, 500, 300);
    //5 - finally set the scene to the stage and show it
    primaryStage.setScene(helloworldscene);
    primaryStage.setTitle("JavaFX Testing");
    primaryStage.show(); 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting compiler error for undefined variables.
You are using variable before actually declaring them. In your code, they are defined after you try to use them.

```
primaryStage.setScene(helloworldscene);
...
Scene helloworldscene = new Scene(root, 500, 300);
```

should be

```
Scene helloworldscene = new Scene(root, 500, 300);
primaryStage.setScene(helloworldscene);
```

Same thing with the `root` variable

Comment: Thanks, I didn't think the order would actually be that important haha.